# Why is -0.x^0.x -nan(ind)

Tags: c++, nan

My program was malfunctioning for some reason, and I discovered it was because I have a calculation that comes down to pow(-0.2, 0.2) which resolves to -nan(ind) when it's called.

If it was an extremely small or extremely large number I would understand, but why does C++ resolve this calculation as -nan(ind)? And is there any way to make it output the correct value (-0.72477966367)?

Comment: Do you just need to solve `x ^ (1/5)`, or can the exponent be other numbers as well?

Comment: The exponent can be other numbers as well, that's what complicates things :\

Comment: is it always of the form `x ^ (k / odd_number)`?

Comment: This is not allowed because in most cases non-integer exponents of negative values give a complex result. While there are theoretically some exponents that would give a real result (including 1/5), there would be no point in allowing them because they can't be represented exactly using floating-point.

Comment: @kennytm No, both the base and the exponent can literally be any double in the range of -1000 and 1000, pretty much. Most are centered around 0 though.

Comment: If you expect any double as input, you will get plenty of NaNs anyway, like for pow(-3, 0.5555). Is a non-NaN result for those inverse odd numbers required?

Comment: If you want a complex result, you can use the overload of `std::pow` that takes `std::complex` parameters.

Comment: @Suma Yes, it is. It's quite dumb of me, I'd never realised C++ would have trouble with any sort of calculation. I programmed the entire thing first and only now noticed these values weren't being calculated correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it output the correct value like this:

```
template <typename T> int sgn(T val) {
    return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
}

template <class T, class U> auto safe_pow(T val, U p) -> decltype(pow(val, p)) {
    return pow(abs(val), p) * sgn(val);
}

auto x = safe_pow(-0.2, 0.2);
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/PieRYz)

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to implement this code I get errors C3551 and 4430: 
if a trailing return type is used then the leading return type shall be the single type-specifier 'auto' (not 'int')
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 

I've tried some things but didn't manage to fix it, any chance you could tell me how to get it working?

Comment: @Milan fixed... Just a `auto` missing before `safe_pow`. Live demo link added.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you so much. Can't believe I didn't figure out to add auto there, haha.

Comment: Note this handles 1/odd as OP expects, but it provides an answer even if there is no real answer, like for safe_pow(-3, 0.5555)

Answer (score 6):

I guess you want to compute fifth root of a negative number, which can be written as x ^ (1/n). However C and C++ `pow` does not support this. See [pow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) documentation:

> If the base is finite negative and the exponent is finite but not an integer value, it causes a domain error.

Comment: Thanks, I sadly only understood that a minute after I posted the question but I figured I shouldn't delete it anyway. Problematically, this is quite important to my program. Do you know of a way I can solve this?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi On Python 2 `(-0.2) ** 0.2` raises ValueError. On Python 3 it returns `(0.5863590650926145+0.4260147974712481j)`.

Comment: @kenny, on my Python 3.4.3, `-0.2 ** 0.2` yields `-0.7247796636776955`. *(Edit: I understand now. The parentheses matter.)*

Comment: I guess handling of special cases of inverted odd number exponents was not deemed important enough to justify complicated implementation and specification. You need to detect and handle those cases on your own.

Comment: @Suma: It's also ill-defined, since `0.2` is not exactly one fifth (thanks to the usual difficulties with binary floating-point). So anything that interpreted it as such would have to be a bit magic.